# ajax internal 500 error on iOS

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to read a text file using ajax, but it doesn't work on ios : I get an error 500 (Internal Server Error) on the proDB.txt file on iOS only.

```
var prodata=[];
ajaxreadfile();

function ajaxreadfile() {
    return $.ajax({
            url: "proDB.txt",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'text',
            headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
            success: function(data){
                readfile(data);
            },
            async: false
        });
}  

function readfile(data){
    var lines=data.split(/\n/);
    var i;
    prodata.push(0);
    var fieldnames=lines[0].split(/\t/);
    for (i = 1; i < lines.length-1; ++i) {
        var fields=lines[i].split(/\t/);
        prodata.push(i);            
        var j;
        prodata[i]={};
        prodata[i]['id']=i; //auto id, there is no more 'id' column in the DB file.
        for (j = 0; j < fields.length; ++j) {
            var str=fieldnames[j];
            prodata[i][str]=fields[j];  
        }
    }

    prodata.sort(SortByName);

    resetLists(prodata);

    prodata.sort(SortById);
}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong ?

Comment: 500 server error is a.... server error. What browser/client you are using really shouldn't affect anything. In either case, since it's a server error, you should be able to find an error in your server logs if debugging is enabled. Getting a 500 error on a .txt file is very weird.

Comment: I know but i only have this error with iOS. On android, firefox, chrome, no problem.

Comment: Server: "Oh this request is from iOS, I'd better crash this time"; You see, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: yeah I know, how do you explain this ??  it seems that just writing a relative path bothers iOS, and not other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, I use the full path to the file for iOS like this :

```
var request = $.ajax({
        url: dbUrl(),
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: successCallback
    });

function dbUrl(){
    if(isIOS()){
        return "http://www.mysite.com/proDB.txt";
    }else{
        return "proDB.txt";
    }
}
function isIOS(){
    return (
       (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) ||
       (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPod") != -1) ||
       (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPad") != -1)
    );
}
```